# What causes the Windows error FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, hardware-failure

A Windows 10 machine crashed with a blue screen that reports `FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE`.

[image: FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE]

Does this actually indicate failing/dying hardware as the error code suggests (perhaps RAM?) or could this have other causes such as faulty drivers?

Is there a recommended method of troubleshooting this error?

Answer (score 2):

Per [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557329(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE bug check has a value of 0x00000128. This bug check indicates that a single-bit error was found in this page. This is a hardware memory error.

Try running a memory diagnostic such as [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/). This will tell where the problem is located so you can determine which memory module needs to be replaced.